# how to color data points on a box plot by certain observations of a group in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, jitter

i'm trying to add colors to my data points on my boxplot based on a certain group but only a subset of observations within that group. For example:

I have a data set looks kind of like this

```
Value   Make   Location
40      Honda   USA
50      Toyota  CHINA
60      Ford    FRANCE
70      Subaru  CHINA
50      Honda   BRAZIL
50      Toyota  SPAIN
30      Nissan  CANADA
```

i'm plotting a box plot looking at the value variable on the y axis and make variable on the x axis. Then i want to add all the data points to my boxplot and color only the ones where the location = china, brazil, and spain (all different colors) while the other data points that are not china, brazil, and spain would just be black.

This is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)

data %>% ggplot(aes(x=Make, y=Value)) +
         geom_boxplot() +
         geom_jitter(aes(color=Location))
```

but this colors all the data points based on the location variable. i need the points colored only when location is china, brazil, and spain but still showing all the data points. how could i achieve this? any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create an extra column that says "Others" if it doesn't have the countries you want. Then, use `scale_color_manual` to enter the colors you want.

```r
library(data.table)
df <- fread('Value   Make   Location
40      Honda   USA
50      Toyota  CHINA
60      Ford    FRANCE
70      Subaru  CHINA
50      Honda   BRAZIL
50      Toyota  SPAIN
30      Nissan  CANADA')

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:data.table':
#> 
#>     between, first, last
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)
visible_ctr <- c('BRAZIL','CHINA','SPAIN')
df %>% 
  mutate(lcat=if_else(Location %in% visible_ctr,Location,'Others')) %>% 
  mutate(lcat=factor(lcat,levels = c(visible_ctr,'Others'))) %>% # Reorder legend
  ggplot(aes(x=Make, y=Value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter(aes(color=lcat)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(BRAZIL='blue',CHINA='red',SPAIN='yellow',Others='black'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>